# Dynamic variable containing numbers

Tags: coldfusion

I've tried everything I've found that might be applicable to this, without success to date.

I have variables that look like

> x000Foo

I'm trying to create one of these dynamically in form scope from query results and have tried the following, and a few others, without success:

```
<cfloop query="qFormFields">

    <cfset "form.x000#fieldname#" = 0>
    You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn as a structure with members

    <cfset "form.x[000]#fieldname#" = 0>
    The value x000AA_report cannot be converted to a number. 

    <cfset form["x000#fieldname#"] = 0>
    The value x000AA_report cannot be converted to a number. 

</cfloop
```

I know it's related to the zeros, but I'm not sure how to get around it without resorting to renaming these variables throughout the application.

I'm on ColdFusion2016

Comment: By `create one of these dynamically in form scope from query results`, do you mean you are trying to change the value of form fields after the form has been submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do: but here's how you can do dynamic variables:

```
<cfset fieldname = "foo">
<cfset form["x000" & fieldname] = 0>
<cfdump var="#form#">
<!--- variable form.x000Foo = 0 --->
```

[Runnable example on TryCF.com](http://trycf.com/gist/bf9b6531d8f52fb8027fd1e9cb29527e/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: Doesn't work. That gives the error "The value x000Blah cannot be converted to a number

Comment: @user460114 Working fine. Check [this](http://trycf.com/gist/bf9b6531d8f52fb8027fd1e9cb29527e/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Comment: Not working for me for whatever reason. Frustrating stuff. Might be related to CF12 or the query loop. This is indeed the correct answer however, although I had already tried it without success.

Comment: Use `queryNew()` and create an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on http://trycf.com that reproduces this issue, and I am sure someone can spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `evaluate` function [read more](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f4e.html)

```
<cfloop query="qFormFields">
      <cfset fieldvalue = Evaluate("form.x000#fieldname#")>
      <cfdump var="#fieldvalue#">
</cfloop>
```

let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: The form scope is a structure, so no need for evaluate(). Just use associative array notation, ie `form["x000"& dynamicFieldName] = "value"`